# Trying to use route session delete to sign out but that route is trying to redirect to session get

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

i installed pow elixir package for phoenix authentication management,registeration route its working but when i am trying to sign out with pow session with method delete its not working and complaining

> no route found for GET /session (QazalbashWeb.Router)

with the pow and session these are only available routes

```
pow_session_path  GET     /session/new                             Pow.Phoenix.SessionController :new
pow_session_path  POST    /session                                 Pow.Phoenix.SessionController :create
pow_session_path  DELETE  /session                                 Pow.Phoenix.SessionController :delete
```

What i am doing on the front-end is this, Register is working fine but not sign out

```
<%= link "Sign Out", to: Routes.pow_session_path(@conn, :delete), method: :delete  %>
<%= link "Register", to: Routes.pow_registration_path(@conn, :new) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a problem with phoenix js not loading properly. Make sure you have `import 'phoenix_html'` in your app.js. It could also possibly be related to [updated dependencies](https://elixirforum.com/t/method-delete-is-not-working-in-multiple-locations-in-my-phoenix-app/7110/7). The gist of the link is to remove your node_modules and do fresh install and see if that works.

```
cd assets && rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```